# Error when knitting a 'flexdashboard' themed with 'bslib'

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard, bslib

I tried a 'flexdashboard' themed with 'bslib' (in RStudio: New file -> Rmarkdown -> From template -> flexdashboard themed with bslib). I'm on Windows. When I knit the file (e.g. the default one), the compilation reaches 100% but then an error occurs:

```
Error in ie_get_proxy_for_url(test_url) : 
  ERROR_WINHTTP_UNABLE_TO_DOWNLOAD_SCRIPT
Calls : <Anonymous> ... download_file -> <Anonymous> -> ie_get_proxy_for_url
```

Comment: Does it work when you have a `flexdashboard` without `bslib`?

Comment: It works nice. Add your default file. We will try to knit.